# The font size of the Flutter inspector panel is too big

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image]

The Flutter Inspector panel is very large. Can someone please help me to fix the font size of the panel? I've just started learning Flutter/Android studio and it's really annoying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've selected 'Experiments'. Follow these steps for fix:

1. File
2. Settings
3. Languages & Frameworks
4. Flutter Experiments
5. unselect 'Enable embedding DevTools' in the Flutter Inspector tool window
6. Apply/OK
7. Restart Android Studio for changes to take effect.

Comment: very helpful answer